# Error: Cannot find module (heroku deploy error)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, model, mern

I have been trying to deploy my MERN app and but am getting this error.

This is the error i have been getting every time it try to deploy the mern app on heroku it's getting deployed but then in logs i am getting this error and link is also not working

[refer to this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Izfii.jpg)

Comment: read an error "can't fid module"...

Answer (score 0):

Why do you export your model like that??

What happen if you only require the file

```
    const generalUser = require("../models/GeneralUsers.js")
```